# Quartz Composer Custom Image Kernel XCode 8

Tags: xcode, core-image, quartz-composer

I'm interested in testing a custom image filter kernel using Quartz Composer. This seems like it should be possible given the docs (see Figure 9-2):
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_custom_filters/ci_custom_filters.html

I have installed Quartz Composer (via the XCode 8 tools), however, I can't find any option that allows me to enter my custom kernel shader code. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: did u manage to solve this?

Comment: @GeneCode Nope. If you figure something out please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In quartz composer go to the patch library (Command-Return default shortcut key) search for core image filter. You can load that into composition by double clicking or if its the top of your search hit Return. Click on the patch that you loaded in and go to the patch settings panel (Command-2 default shortcut). Place your code in the text field.

You can drag and drop a image in and wire the output image to your input of your core image filter patch. You need to wire it to a rendering patch to see it rendered in your viewer. Dropping in a billboard will help facilitate that. If you set the billboard's width to 2, it should fill viewers screen.

Comment: this doesnt work. in inspector Cmd+2 shows settings, but no text editor to enter code.

Comment: Still works for me in MacOS 10.14, is the core image filter selected when opening the patch inspector?

Comment: Yup. It is selected.

Comment: Just to check which version of Composer are u using? im using 4.6.2 recently downloaded.

Comment: I'm using 4.6.1, They stopped supporting it in os10.6, I'm very surprised there was an update.